# Count differnce of two Date's with Respect that every month has EXACT 30 days

Tags: t-sql

I thought it was clear, but doesn't seem so.
This question is about T-SQL (since it's tagged with tsql :) )

So I couldn't find any out-of-the-box solution to calculate my problem.

Let's assume you have these two dateTimes:

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '2011-01-01',
    @end DATETIME = '2011-04-15'
```

The difference of these two datetimes in Days should be quivalent to 105.

The calculation works as follows: For every full month add 30 days, for the rest add the days till the date is achieved.

I could program this, but it would be an enormous SQL-statement, which I find find kinda ugly.

Is there any simple solution for this, like a built-in function or something short?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved it this way now:  `SELECT (30 - DAY(@start) + 1)
  + (MONTH(@end) - MONTH(@start) - 1) * 30
  + ((YEAR(@end) - YEAR(@start)) * 12 * 30)
  + CASE DAY(@end) WHEN 31 THEN 30 ELSE DAY(@end) END`. Seems like the smallest and most elegant way I can work out. Other solutions are happily welcome though!

Comment: that looks pretty similar to my answer.  My only other suggestion would be that you could move that logic to a function yourself, which would really let you clean up the code that uses it.

Comment: @Shion - I've put in an answer that addresses the example above, could you add a couple more examples in so I can test it a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

There's no built in function, but you could pretty easily create your own to handle converting a datetime to an int.  From there, the SQL you would have to write would be trivial.

**Long Answer**

There's no built in function that will do this, probably because every month *doesn't* have 30 days.  :)

You can start with this:

```sql
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '2011-01-01',
        @end DATETIME = '2011-04-15'

DECLARE @endConverted INT
SELECT @endConverted = DATEPART(month, @end) * 30 
                       + CASE 
                           WHEN DATEPART(DAY, @end) <= 30 
                             THEN datepart(DAY, @end)  
                           ELSE 30 
                         END

DECLARE @startConverted INT
SELECT @startConverted = DATEPART(MONTH, @start) * 30
                         + CASE
                             WHEN DATEPART(DAY, @start) <= 30
                               THEN DATEPART(DAY, @start)
                             ELSE 30
                           END

SELECT @endConverted - @startConverted
```

This isn't beautiful SQL, but it works.  Note that it returns 104 (because 15 days - 1 day = 14 days), but simple enough to tack on a `+ 1` to the end of the final select if you want to handle the boundry days differently.

Note that the math here could pretty easily be moved into a function, which would allow you to clean your SQL up.  Let's assume you created a function called `GetDateTimeAsInt` which holds the math; your SQL could be as simple as

```
DECLARE @start INT = GetDateTimeAsInt('2011-01-01'),
        @end INT = GetDateTimeAsInt('2011-04-15')

SELECT @end - @start -- may need to add 1 here
```

In my testing, this seems to work.  It will return the same result as the `DATEDIFF` function for the date range you specify in your post, but this is because there are 2 days with 31 days and 1 day with 28, so effectively, Jan - April have 30 days each.  If you use it with a wider date range, you'll begin to get different results with my code vs. the `DATEDIFF` function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please see the comment of the post of Davin. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick?

```
;with dates as
(
SELECT
CAST ('2011-01-01' AS DATETIME) as start_date
,CAST('2011-04-15' AS DATETIME) as end_date
)
SELECT 
start_date
,end_date
,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MM,start_date,end_date) = 0 THEN DAY(end_date) - DAY(start_date) 
        WHEN DAY(start_date) = 1 THEN (30 * (DATEDIFF(MM,start_date,end_date))) + DAY(end_date) 
        WHEN DAY(start_date) <> 1 THEN  30 * DATEDIFF(MM,start_date,end_date) + (DAY(end_date) - DAY(start_date))
        END AS gap_in_days
FROM dates
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution and works quite perfectly. I'll upvote it, but I can't mark it as the correct answer since Jeremy Wiggins has provided another solution which works, but sooner. Thanks though! Great script.

Comment: @shion - no worries just glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I use  [PERIODDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff). To get the year and the month of the date, I use the function  [EXTRACT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract):

```
  SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW()), EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM time)) AS months FROM your_table;
```

T-sql

```
    SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, "2011-01-01","2011-04-15")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I was talking about T-SQL and there is no PERIOD_DIFF method. :). I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Your example from DateDiff with my example-dates get's 104 Days. I've had this already. The result should be 105 Days (like I stated: Every month has 30 days, February and March, too :))

Comment: did u try the SELECT DATEDIFF(month,"2011-01-01","2011-04-15") or day

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I need. I.e. 2011-01-03 and 2011-04-15 would return 3 months, but that would only be 2 whole months. Seems like I have to stick with some big ugly statement to do it for now. ;)

Comment: Oops sorry mate can't help... hopefully u wil get a answer